# How could I order latests products in Magento?

Tags: php, collections, magento, sql-order-by

I'm trying to show the latest products on my magento store.

What is a recent product? It is defined by two criteria:

- created_at
- news_from_date

I'd like to order my product indifferently between created_at & news_from_date, not one criteria first, and the second after.

Any ideas?

I already tried the following code:

```
->addAttributeToSort('created_at, news_from_date', 'desc')
```

OR

```
->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc')
```

OR

```
->addAttributeToSort(array('created_at' => 'desc', 'news_from_date' => 'desc'))
```

OR

```
->addAttributeToSort(array('created_at', 'news_from_date'), 'desc'))
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no "OR" in SQL order clauses so you need to find a way to reduce the problem to a single column. The following is untested but should give you an idea.

```
// Make sure the correct attributes are available with names we choose.
$products->addAttributeToSelect('created_at, news_from_date');

// Choose the LATEST date to sort as it is the most RECENT.
$products->addOrder('MAX(created_at, news_from_date)', 'desc');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can order/sort latest products by both **created_at** and **news_from_date** attributes at a time.

Here is the code to do so:-

```
$todayDate  = Mage::app()->getLocale()->date()->toString(Varien_Date::DATETIME_INTERNAL_FORMAT);

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                ->getCollection()                   
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_from_date', array('date' => true, 'to' => $todayDate))
                ->addAttributeToFilter('news_to_date', array('or'=> array(
                    0 => array('date' => true, 'from' => $todayDate),
                    1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
                ), 'left')
                ->addAttributeToSort('news_from_date', 'desc')
                ->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'desc');
```

Thanks.

Comment: 'left' means LEFT JOIN. The last parameter of addAttributeToFilter is the join type.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using the news_from_date instead of the created date.  This gives you the flexibility to create content ahead of time, but still appear in the correct order when you publish it.

Answer (score 0):

Better:

```
$_productCollection = $this->getLoadedProductCollection()->clear()->addAttributeToSort('created_at', 'DESC')->setPageSize(4);
```